# Can I mount an SSHFS drive via port 21 with FTP-SSL?

Tags: macos, mac, ftp, sshfs, fuse

I'm on a mac and have been using CyberDuck FTP to connect to a client's server. It is an ASP/IIS server and when I connect to it CyberDuck tells me

> This server can support more secure FTP-SSL connections

That's great - so I click on the OK button and it connects via `FTP-SSL`.

Well, I want to be able to mount that volume on my Mac and I think that `SSHFS` should work.

I've installed `sshfs` and `fuse4x` using `homebrew` but now I can't connect to this server.

I made a directory to mount it to:

```
mkdir ~/fuse-mnt
```

The I try to mount it:

```
sshfs -p 21 myusername@ftp.webhost.net:~ ~/fuse-mnt/ -d
```

I've added the `-d` for debugging but it just hangs without a real error

```
FUSE library version: 2.8.7
nullpath_ok: 0
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
remote host has disconnected
```

I've also tried port 21 with `-p 21` because that appears to be the port that CyberDuck connects on.

I read [this tutorial](http://www.read-write.fr/blog/blog/2012/02/26/my-guide-for-sshfs/) and also tried using the following options:

```
-oauto_cache,reconnect,defer_permissions,negative_vncache,volname=RemoteHome
```

None of this is working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing SSH and SSL, which are different protocols. Likewise, `sshfs` is a SFTP client – as in "SSH File Transfer Protocol". It does not support FTP, which is a completely different protocol, nor FTPS (aka FTP-SSL or FTP-TLS), which is FTP inside SSL.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me. Can you recommend some ways to mount `ftps` volumes on Mac OS X? What I really want to do is to be able to download / backup the site - and then do this again and only get things that have changed. I was hoping to do this via `rsync` if I could mount the drive.

Comment: i will accept a different answer if someone else can provide better insight on this.